# Problem in displaying data in template in Angular

Tags: angular

After fetching data from Django server I want to display it in Angular, I used :

```
 <p>
  {{todo.id}}
</p>
```

and without any errors, I do not see the data in my template, the above code wants to display the value of `id` in a JSON.

service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

  }
  private URL="http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/product/"
  getApi(arg:any){
    console.log(arg);
    return this.http.get (this.URL)
    .subscribe(data=> {
      console.log('we got',data)
    })
    console.log(arg);
    
  }
  
}
```

component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']

})
export class AppComponent {
   
  title = 'angpr';
  todo:any;

  constructor(public api: ApiService) {

    

  }

 ngOnInit(): void{
  this.todo=this.api.getApi('hey');

 }

}
```

Why can't I see the data in template and what should I do to display it in the template?

Comment: Don’t subscribe in your service, just return the observable and subscribe in the component.

Answer (score 1):

In your TS file you assign **this.todo** to the result of **this.api.getApi()**, however the result of that function is a subscription and not data that comes from subscribing.

You can rewrite this to:

service.ts:

```
getApi(arg:any):Observable<any>{
    console.log(arg);
    return this.http.get (this.URL)    
}
```

And in your component.ts:

```
this.api.getApi('hey').subscribe(
   result => this.todo = result
)
```

In this way your service is responsible for interacting with the backend and your view is responsible for assigning the data from the service to the correct attributes in your component.

Hope this helps.

PS. You don't use the **arg** parameter in the function.